# Using Hadoop for the First Time, MapReduce Job does not run Reduce Phase

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I wrote a simple map reduce job that would read in data from the DFS and run a simple algorithm on it. When trying to debug it I decided to simply make the mappers output a single set of keys and values, and the reducers output an entirely different set. I am running this job on a single node Hadoop 20.2 cluster. When the job is finished the output contains simply the values that were outputted by the mappers leading me to believe that the reducer is not being run. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone provide any insight as to why my code is producing such output. I have tried setting the outputKeyClass and outputValueClass to different things as well as the setMapOutputKeyClass and setMapOutputValueClass to different things. Currently the commented our sections of code are the algorithm that I am running, but I have changed the map and reduce methods to simply output certain values. Once again, the output from the job contains only the values that were outputted by the mapper. Here is the class I used to run the job:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public class CalculateHistogram {

    public static class HistogramMap extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Text> {

        private static final int R = 100;
        private int n = 0;

        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            if (n == 0) {
                StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), ",");
                int counter = 0;
                while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    String token = tokens.nextToken();
                    if (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
                        context.write(new LongWritable(-2), new Text("HI"));
                        //context.write(new LongWritable(counter), new Text(token));
                    }
                    counter++;
                    n++;
                }
            } else {
                n++;
                if (n == R) {
                    n = 0;
                }
                
            }
        }
    }

    public static class HistogramReduce extends Reducer<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, HistogramBucket> {

        private final static int R = 10;

        public void reduce(LongWritable key, Iterator<Text> values, Context context)
                                            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            if (key.toString().equals("-1")) {
                //context.write(key, new HistogramBucket(key));
            }
            Text t = values.next();
            for (char c : t.toString().toCharArray()) {
                if (!Character.isDigit(c) && c != '.') {
                    //context.write(key, new HistogramBucket(key));//if this isnt a numerical attribute we ignore it
                }
            }
            context.setStatus("Building Histogram");
            HistogramBucket i = new HistogramBucket(key);
            i.add(new DoubleWritable(Double.parseDouble(t.toString())));
            while (values.hasNext()) {
                for (int j = 0; j < R; j++) {
                    t = values.next();
                }
                if (!i.contains(Double.parseDouble(t.toString()))) {
                    context.setStatus("Writing a value to the Histogram");
                    i.add(new DoubleWritable(Double.parseDouble(t.toString())));
                }
            }
            
            context.write(new LongWritable(55555555), new HistogramBucket(new LongWritable(55555555)));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> <out>");
            System.exit(2);
        }

        Job job = new Job(conf, "MRDT - Generate Histogram");
        job.setJarByClass(CalculateHistogram.class);
        job.setMapperClass(HistogramMap.class);
        job.setReducerClass(HistogramReduce.class);

        //job.setOutputValueClass(HistogramBucket.class);
        
        //job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
        //job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to have the @Override annotation before you define the reduce() method

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The signature of your reduce method is wrong. Your method signature contains `Iterator<Text>`. You have to pass an `Iterable<Text>`.

Your code does not override the `reduce` method of the `Reducer` base class. Because of this, the default imlementation provided by the `Reducer` base class is used. This implementation is an identity function.

Use the `@Override` annotation to anticipate errors like this one.

Comment: Thanks a lot that was exactly what was wrong, I had tried adding the @Override before but it wouldn't compile. I guess I was just looking at it too long and missed the Iterator/Iterable bit

Comment: The fact that RedbearTheNinja is having problems with @Override should be a concern. I've run in to cases myself where reducers specifically have this problem. I forget why.