# Not getting correct output when running standard "WordCount" program using Hadoop0.20.2

Tags: hadoop

I'm new to Hadoop.I have been trying to run the famous "WordCount" program -- which counts the total number of words
in a list of files using Hadoop-0.20.2.
I'm using single node cluster.

Following is my program:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {

    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String line = value.toString();
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
                context.write(word, one);
            }
        }
    } 

    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            while (values.hasNext()) {
                ++sum ;
            }
            context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");        
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));        
        job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);       

        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);          
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);              
        job.setNumReduceTasks(5);        
        job.waitForCompletion(true);       

    }

}
```

Suppose input file is A.txt which has following contents

A B C D A B C D

When I run this program using hadoop-0.20.2 (not showing commands for sake of clarity) ,the output that comes is 
A 1
A 1
B 1
B !
C 1
C 1
D !
D 1

which is wrong.The actual output should be :
A 2
B 2
C 2
D 2

This "WordCount" program is pretty standard program. I'm not sure what is wrong with this code.
I have written the contents of all configuration files like mapred-site.xml , core-site.xml etc correctly.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This code actually runs a local mapreduce job. If you want to submit this to the real cluster, you have to provide the `fs.default.name` and the `mapred.job.tracker` configuration parameter. These keys are mapped to your machine with a host:port pair. Just like in your mapred/core-site.xml.
Make sure your data is available in HDFS and not on local disk, as well as your number of reducers should be reduced. That's about 2 records per reducer. You should set this to 1.

Answer (score 0):

reduce signature is incorrect.
Second parameter is Iterable type and not Iterator

http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html

See also [Using Hadoop for the First Time, MapReduce Job does not run Reduce Phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253286/using-hadoop-for-the-first-time-mapreduce-job-does-not-run-reduce-phase)