# Hadoop - Join with MultipleInputs probably skips Reducer

Tags: hadoop

So, I want to perform a reduce side join with MR. (No Hive or anything, I'm experimenting on vanilla Hadoop atm).

I have 2 input files, first goes like this: 
12 13
12 15
12 16
12 23

the second is simply 12 1000.

So I assign each file to a separate mapper which actually tags each key value pair with 0 or 1 depending on its source file. And that works well. How I can tell?
I get the MapOutput as expected:

| key | |value|
 12 0   1000
 12 1   13
 12 1   15
 12 1   16 etc

My Partitioner partitions based on first part of key (ie 12).
The Reducer should join by key. Yet, the job seems to skip the reduce step.

I wonder if there's something wrong with my Driver?

My code (Hadoop v0.22, but same results with 0.20.2 with extra libs from the trunk):

Mappers

```
public static class JoinDegreeListMapper extends
        Mapper<Text, Text, TextPair, Text> {
    public void map(Text node, Text degree, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        context.write(new TextPair(node.toString(), "0"), degree);

    }
}

public static class JoinEdgeListMapper extends
        Mapper<Text, Text, TextPair, Text> {
    public void map(Text firstNode, Text secondNode, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        context.write(new TextPair(firstNode.toString(), "1"), secondNode);

    }
}
```

Reducer

```
public static class JoinOnFirstReducer extends
        Reducer<TextPair, Text, Text, Text> {
    public void reduce(TextPair key, Iterator<Text> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        context.progress();
        Text nodeDegree = new Text(values.next());
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            Text secondNode = values.next();
            Text outValue = new Text(nodeDegree.toString() + "\t"
                    + secondNode.toString());
            context.write(key.getFirst(), outValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Partitioner

```
public static class JoinOnFirstPartitioner extends
        Partitioner<TextPair, Text> {

    @Override
    public int getPartition(TextPair key, Text Value, int numOfPartitions) {
        return (key.getFirst().hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numOfPartitions;
    }
}
```

Driver

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {


    Path edgeListPath = new Path(args[0]);
    Path nodeListPath = new Path(args[1]);
    Path outputPath = new Path(args[2]);

    Configuration conf = getConf();

    Job job = new Job(conf);
    job.setJarByClass(JoinOnFirstNode.class);
    job.setJobName("Tag first node with degree");

    job.setPartitionerClass(JoinOnFirstPartitioner.class);
    job.setGroupingComparatorClass(TextPair.FirstComparator.class);
    //job.setSortComparatorClass(TextPair.FirstComparator.class);
    job.setReducerClass(JoinOnFirstReducer.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(TextPair.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);


    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, edgeListPath, EdgeInputFormat.class,
            JoinEdgeListMapper.class);
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, nodeListPath, EdgeInputFormat.class,
            JoinDegreeListMapper.class);

            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputPath);


    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;

}
```

Comment: `Yet, the job seems to skip the reduce step.` - why? Did you check log files?

Comment: The log files say the attempt on the reducer is completed.
Still, (let alone the fact that the result I'm getting is just a sorted list of the output from both mappers ^ ), even if I remove the reducer class I still get the same results.

Comment: Did you try sysout to see if the reducer is called or not?I looked at the code and I don't see anything wrong in it.

Comment: INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Task:attempt_201201280042_0002_r_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting  
INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Task attempt_201201280042_0002_r_000000_0 is allowed to commit now  
INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter: Saved output of task 'attempt_201201280042_0002_r_000000_0' to /home/hduser/output  INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_201201280042_0002_r_000000_0' done.

Answer (score 0):

My reduce function had Iterator<> instead of Iterable, so the job skipped to Identity Reducer.
I can't quite believe I overlooked that. Noob error.

And the answer came from this Q/A
[Using Hadoop for the First Time, MapReduce Job does not run Reduce Phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253286/using-hadoop-for-the-first-time-mapreduce-job-does-not-run-reduce-phase)